# Inserting a char (a to z) in between each character in a word

Tags: java, char

I am working on a spell checker. I have implemented the hash table which takes in the word list, but now I have to write  five techniques that are used to generate possible word suggestions. One of them is

1. Swapping adjacent characters
2. Insert a character in between each character

For example:

I have the word "bob"... I wanna be able to insert a char in between (a-z)b (a-z)o (a-z)b(a-z) to see if I can get a new word that could be a possible suggestion for the miss spelled word

This is what I did so far...but doesn't work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "evelina";

    char[] wordCharArr = word.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i < wordCharArr.length ; i++) {
        //char temp1 = wordCharArr[i];
        for(char j = 'A'; j <= 'Z' ; j++) {
            word.substring(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to try every letter a-z in each spot and then move to the next? Like you'd check "abob", "bbob", ... "zbob", "baob", "bbob", ... "bobz"? Or do you want to check every possible combination with letters in every spot?

Comment: yes windle. check a-z in each spot in front of each letter of the word including the back spot of the last letter. exactly as she had described.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was add some code which makes an ArrayList (essentially an unlimited array), and then fills it with all of the possibilities found from switching around one letter. It also prints out each one, but you can remove that.

The only changes I made were:

1.Adding the ArrayList

2.Fixing your outer loop; It is one character short (Bob requires 4 iterations, not 3)

3.Adding in additional sub-string segments to account for the rest of the word.

Elements can be retrieved by words.get(a); where 'a' is a int within the bounds of the Array-list. Don't forget the import statement, import java.util.*;

This would also be more efficient then Jeff's solution, because instead of having to check the entire dictionary, and then remove every single element from the dictionary like suggested below, it would simply have to check the dictionary with all of the ~100 possibilities. Because a dictionary is in alphabetical order, it can be searched very quickly, but removing each entry (nearly 100000 words) would be less efficient.

```
import java.util.*;
public class spellcheck {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "evelina";
    char[] wordCharArr = word.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i <= wordCharArr.length ; i++) {
        for(char j = 'A'; j <= 'Z' ; j++) {
            words.add(word.substring(0,i) + j + word.substring(i,wordCharArr.length));
    System.out.println(word.substring(0,i) + j + word.substring(i,wordCharArr.length));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your for loop. Instead of only looping through every other letter of the word you're checking. You're looping through EVERY letter including the original. The outer for loop should be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, but i'm not sure if it's easier or harder to implement (it sounds easier to me at least).  Rather than looping over every character and inserting it into the word, you could build a simple query mechanism like so:

```
 Input: b?ob
```

So your algorithm would be something like:

```
 1) Start with your entire word list
 2) Remove all words that don't start with b
 3) You can "ignore" the ?
 4) Remove all words that don't have a 'o' in the 3rd position
 5) Remove all words that don't have a 'b' in the 4th position
 6) Return the results
```

Then you go through each of the options

```
 Input 2: bo?b
 Input 3: bob?
```